Networkx python module function GraphMatcher.subgraph_is_isomorphic() usage
isomatcher = nx.isomorphism.GraphMatcher(G, H)
isomatcher.subgraph_is_isomorphic()


In my understanding this function returns True if a subgraph of G is isomorphic to H.
Yet when I run this code as follows:
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([0,1,2,3])
G.add_edges_from([(0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)])

H = nx.Graph()
H.add_nodes_from([0,1,2,3,4,5])
H.add_edges_from([(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5)])
isomatcher = nx.isomorphism.GraphMatcher(H, G)
print(isomatcher.subgraph_is_isomorphic())

The output is false, although obviously G is isomorphic to some subgraph of H since H is the complete graph on 6 vertices.
I tried changing the vertex indices to different numbers but it did not help.
I believe I have incorrect understanding of this function.
Can someone explain it to me?
